How does a sender routing a payment using a blinded path know what the fees are needed in the blinded portion of the path?
How does a sender routing a payment using a blinded path know what the fees are needed in the blinded portion of the path? Are some net fee hints somehow included in the blinded path? For a normal un blinded path, the sender should know the path they are constructing and know the fees that are expected on each hop (because each node advertises their fees).
Most routing algorithms have a tradeoff of trying to find a route quicker at higher probability with payment of higher fees vs trying to get the payment to route potentially more slowly at a lower cost, but lower probability of success. I'm not sure how this can be accomplished with blinded paths.

I think the amount (including the fees for the blinded path) that have to arrive at the rendezvous point will be included in the blinded path that is being communicated. The sender cannot trade fees for probability within the blinded path. In fact he has to hope the recipient knew the blinded path can forward the payment if the sender can bring it to the rendezvous point

I think you are right. Here are some comments in BOLT4: https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/247e83d528a2a380e533e89f31918d7b0ce6a0c1/04-onion-routing.md?plain=1#L587 and https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/247e83d528a2a380e533e89f31918d7b0ce6a0c1/04-onion-routing.md?plain=1#L619 .
